# Using jquery ajax to append content to a div id

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, append

I am using jquery ajax to get the names stored in an xml file and append it to a div id, but having some problems.

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "names.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(xml){ 

        $(xml).find('name').each(function(){ 

              $(this).text().append('#names');


        });

     }});
```

});

my xml file is formatted like so

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <item>
<name>Paul</name>
<name>John</name>
<name>Sam</name>
<name>Mitch</name>
etc.
</item>
```

and need to be appended to div id name.

```
<div id="names">

Paul
John
Sam
Mitch

</div>
```

Help

Comment: The names from the xml file are not being appended to the div id names and i not to sure why so any help would be great.

Comment: Change append, to, **appendTo**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `append` the wrong way round - the element to append to needs to come first:

```
$(xml).find('name').each(function() { 
    $("#name").append($(this).text());
});
```

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55NCM/).

Comment: Many thanks, im fairly new to jQuery but learning as i go along!

Comment: To reverse the order i used prepend!

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/55NCM/2/ (or use `prepend` as you just said! Can't believe I didn't think of that... well done!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function()
{
    var $names = $('#names');

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "names.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(xml)
        {
            var combinedText = $(xml).find('name').map(function()
            { 
                return ' ' + $(this).text();
            }).get().join('');

            $names.text($names.text() + combinedText);
     }});
});
```

#### (non-ajax) Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/yGUCZ/